# Making Mathematica's Global Options stick

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, preferences

I asked [this](https://superuser.com/q/217746/16728) question on Superuser, it has gotten no views in 24 hours. So despite not being a strict programming question, I'm asking it here where all the cool Mathematica kids hang:

I'm trying to set the default for the "Footer on first page" setting in File -> Print Settings -> Headers and Footers... Since that setting is set on a per notebook basis, I'm trying to set the Global Preference (Format -> Options Inspector...) under Notebook Options -> Printing Options -> Printing Options -> FirstPageFooter.

When I set this global preference it stays set, but new notebooks I open still have the "Footer on first page" setting set as well as having their own Preference setting Notebook Options -> etc etc -> FirstPageFooter set to True.

I would have thought that new notebooks inherit global options. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: The reason I want to do this is that I want to get rid of the "Printed by Mathematica for Students" footer/advertisement, so any other way to get rid of it consistently (like altering the resource from where that text gets pulled) will be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for _all the cool Mathematica **kids**_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a kind of "restriction/protection" posed by the Student Version and is not intended to be removed from inside Mathematica.

I found a few posts in the web:

---

[Mathematica for Students has a "Printed by Mathematica for Students" footnote that prints at the bottom of every document page.](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/education/students/moreinfo.en.html?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&width=350&height=300)

---

[There is no way within the Student Versions. If you have access to a professional version (perhaps in a school lab) you could transfer the notebook and print using that version. Or you could use the tried and true White-Out smear. Tom Zeller Forum Moderator](http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/806)

---

However I think you can remove it from the generated output. Just print through a nice driver to a file (a PostScript one, for example), identify the footer (I don't have the Student Version available to help you more on this) and post-process the file replacing the generated text or image for blanks.

I generated (with Mma Std ver) the same .ps file with and without footers and noted that the file is unchanged except for an easily identified block just before the [%%PageTrailer] PostScript directive that can be removed without damage the file integrity.

HTH!

**Edit**

Modifying `Stylesheets\Default.nb` worked for me. Just changed the `"FirstPageHeader"->True` line.

**WARNING** Make a backup copy before modifying !!
HTH!

Comment: I think I was a bit unclear, the question is not about how to remove the "Printed by..." footer. That is easily done via `File -> Print Settings -> Headers and Footers... -> Footer on first page -> Uncheck`, what I'm looking for is how to make that setting a default. Removing the "Printed by..." string via hacking the Mathematica installation is just a suboptimal but acceptable solution.

Comment: I had tried this but upon restart Mathematica would crash. Since it worked for you, I actually read the error message ;-). After also deleting the cache information at the beginning of Default.nb everything is peaches.

Comment: @Timo Something similar here, but I just opened and rewrote the Default.nb _That was the origin of the Warning_ . Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for 7.0.1 Home Edition, which has a header rather than a footer. YMMV.

`SetOptions[$FrontEnd,DockedCells->{}]`

Reference: http://qwan.org/2009/02/07/mathematica-home-editions-banner-ad-revisited/

Comment: This is for the docked header in all the notebooks. I was talking about footers that appear in printouts of notebooks. This thing you mention, however, was the first thing I did when I installed Mathematica (actually I changed `"StudentBar" -> {}` in `SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/MiscExpressions.tr`.

Answer (score -1):

Buy Home Edition....

http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica-home-edition/

Comment: Well .. it's _only_ USD 295, and NOT avaible everywhere ... Also, what are the HE restrictions?

Comment: As far as I know, the only restriction is that it comes only as a 32 bit executable.  There may be some additional restrictions on the number of Wolfram|Alpha API calls/day you get to make too.

Comment: It's more expensive than the student edition, you can't use it for work or research and it's limited to two CPUs. Worse of all for Timo, it has its own banner ad on every page. Oh, and version 8 still isn't out yet!